# Add margins to a th element

Tags: html, css

I've got a table and I would like to add margins to the  elements so I can have a bottom border that doesn't fill the entire table column and the  elements are unaffected. Another way to look at this would be to have a  with border-collapse: separate and  with border-collapse: collapse which doesn't work unfortunately.

I've thought about using two tables one for the header and one for the body. Also changing the th display of the th elements from something other than table-cell. Both are nasty so I'm looking for a better solution than that if one exists.

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VywK7/4/) that's got a table with some css if you want to have quick play at trying to figure this out.

Here's some of the code mostly from my attempts on jsFiddle to try and get this doing what I want.

HTML

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Month</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>January</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>February</td>
      <td>$200</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>​
```

CSS

```
table
{
    width:100%;
    padding:2px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
td
{
    padding:2px;
}
th
{
    border-bottom:2px solid gray;
    padding: 0 2px 5px;
    line-height: 15px;
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;
}
```

EDIT: Hopefully this will illustrate what I'm trying to achieve

```
---------------------------------------------
|Month     |Amount     |Month     |Amount      | <--TH element
|--------   ---------   --------   ---------   | <--bottom border doesn't fill cell
|----------------------------------------------|
|Jan       |$100       |Jan       |$100        |
|----------------------------------------------|
|Feb       |$200       |Feb       |$200        |
|----------------------------------------------|
```

Comment: to clarify you want a border under "$100" that doesn't fill the column?

Comment: I don't think you are allowed to set margins on table cells (header cells or not). But you could use http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/border-spacing

Comment: @DavidNguyen The border would be under the column header only i.e. the th elements. There should be no border under the td elements.

Comment: @biziclop You're right about not being able to add margins to a table cell. I'm trying to figure out if there is a way around that. The border spacing is not quite what I want because your getting a separation between each column. I don't want that just a separation between the bottom borders on the column headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you, this is something like what you want:

http://jsfiddle.net/VywK7/21/

```
th {
    background-color: yellow;
}
th {
    border-top: 4px solid gray;
    border-bottom: 4px solid gray;
}
th:first-child {
    border-left: 4px solid gray;
}
th + th + th + th, /* choose one of these selectors */
th:last-child {
    border-right: 4px solid gray;
}
```

Pseudoelement fun:
​
http://jsfiddle.net/VywK7/23/

```
th:after {
    content: ' ';
    display:block;
    width: 50%;
    background: red;
    height: 4px;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
}
```

Comment: Not quite. The border is solid in this example. I want to have breaks in the border. I edited my original post with an example that I hope better illustrates what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: Nice job! I tried the after pseudoelement with no luck and gave up on that approach. The content: ' ' was the key piece. I didn't know you could do that. Thanks!

Comment: `content` is a bit tricky, it cannot be an empty string. Remember that the `:before/:after` pseudoelements are not supported by IE7.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add the margin to the `td` and/or `th` elements I'm afraid as `tr`s won't accept it.

Comment: This was my very first thought but because the display type of the th/td elements is table-cell there is no margin associated with them.